# Android emulator slow performance on high end intel machine

Tags: android

I know there have been several posts about this, but most of them have to do with `intel virtualization` which I already have enabled, low system specs due to the expensiveness of OpenGL software rendering inside of the ARM emulator, and people attempting to run the emulator with an AMD processor.

> **Processor**: Intel i7 7700K 5.2GHz quad-core processor (Overclocked).
>
> **Memory**: 64GB Dominator Platinum 3000MHz DDR4
>
> **Disk**: Samsung 960PRO M.2
>
> **Intel HAXM**: Enabled

I should add that this is a relatively fresh install of windows with only my development software installed, there are no anti-virus programs or Firewalls that could be affecting performance. All of the programs that ship with windows have been disabled.

The emulator loads up in about 2-3 seconds, however any type of animation or loading inside of applications is extremely slow. Transition animations execute at an estimated 2-3 frames per second which makes emulated development nearly impossible.

Comment: Are you using ARM emulator? If yes, you should use x86 emulator instead. That is the one that can use Intel HAXM. [How to Ensure You Are Using Intel® HAXM for Android Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/10/20/how-to-ensure-you-are-using-intel-haxm-for-android-emulator)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The steps are different using Android Studio, however I'm almost 100% positive I'm making use of HAXM.  `CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)`  I've even gone as far to give the emulator more RAM than any android device has been deployed with and increased the heap considerably, but that didn't help much